# Barchart with statistics as labels

Tags: charts, code-review, code-request

The following code (thanks to @Jagra):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
data = {{1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, 3}};
ndata = DecimalForm[(data[[1]]/Total@Abs[data[[1]]])*100 // N, 2];

Column[{
  TextCell["GDP Per Capital", "Section", FontColor -> White],
  TextCell["This is a scenario parameter set", FontSize -> 12, 
   FontColor -> White], "",
  TextCell["WorldGDP in 2020", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 20],
  TextCell["parameter domain:{1,2,3}", FontWeight -> Bold, 
   FontSize -> 12], "",
  TextCell["% Difference from baseline and contributions in % pts", 
   "TI"],
  BarChart[
   data,
   PlotTheme -> "Business",
   BarOrigin -> Left,
   BarSpacing -> Medium,
   ChartLabels -> {{None}, {"Asia", "South Asia", "South East Asia", 
      "East Asia", "Oceania", "Central Asia", "North Asia"}},
   ChartLegends -> {{ndata}, {None}},
   ChartStyle -> {Red, None},
   ImageSize -> 500
   ]
  },
 Alignment -> Center,
 Background -> {Automatic, {1 -> Darker[Red], 2 -> Darker[Red]}}
 ]
```

generates:

[image]

As seen, `ChartLegends` is not placed properly. I want to create a bar chart as shown in the following example:

[image]

where `ndata` should be inside `green circles` as shown below, with a title of "% total tax shares". Furthermore, the X-axis line should be removed from the bar chart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data = {{1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, 3}};

normalized =  Round[N @ Normalize[data[[1]], Total@*Abs], .001];

labels = {"Asia", "South Asia", "South East Asia", "East Asia", 
      "Oceania", "Central Asia", "North Asia"};

colors = {RGBColor[0.4, 0, 0.2], RGBColor[0.4, 0.7, 1], RGBColor[0.5, 0.7, 0.1]};

cF = If[Positive @ #, colors[[1]], colors[[2]]] &;
```

Construct custom ticks with desired glyphs as labels:

```
rightframeticks = MapIndexed[{First @ #2, #} &, 
   Graphics[{Last @ colors, Disk[], 
       Text[Style[PercentForm @ #, White, FontSize -> 10]]}, 
     ImageSize -> 40] & /@ normalized];
```

Specify `Frame` and `FrameTicks` options in `BarChart` using `rightframeticks` to override option values set by plot themes:

```
BarChart[data[[1]], 
    PlotTheme -> "Business", 
    Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, rightframeticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
    BarOrigin -> Left, 
    ImageSize -> 700, 
    BarSpacing -> Medium,
    ColorFunction -> cF, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    ChartLabels -> {{None}, labels}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is `PercentForm` a new function? Version 11.3 does not recognize it. With what can I substitute it? Thank you very much for the figure.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, `PercentForm` is introduced in v 12.0. In v 11.3 you can replace it with `Quantity[# 100. , "Percent"]`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to display the % on the bar

```
ndata = (data[[1]]/Total@Abs[data[[1]]])*100 // Reverse // N
lFun = Placed[Quantity[Round[ndata[[Last@#2]], 0.1], "Percent"], Center] &;


Column[{TextCell["GDP Per Capital", "Section", FontColor -> White], 
  TextCell["This is a scenario parameter set", FontSize -> 12, FontColor -> White], "", 
  TextCell["WorldGDP in 2020", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 20], 
  TextCell["parameter domain:{1,2,3}", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 12], "", 
  TextCell["% Difference from baseline and contributions in % pts", "TI"],
  BarChart[data,
   PlotTheme -> "Business",
   BarOrigin -> Left,
   BarSpacing -> Medium,
   ChartLabels -> {{"Asia", "South Asia", "South East Asia", 
      "East Asia", "Oceania", "Central Asia", "North Asia"}}, 
   ChartStyle -> {Red, None},
   ImageSize -> 500, LabelingFunction -> lFun]},
 Alignment -> Center,
 Background -> {Automatic, {1 -> Darker[Red], 2 -> Darker[Red]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Rahit Namjoshi: It is a good option, and maybe better than what I thought previously. Is there a way to also show the percentages as a separate column in green circles? Somehow green circles look more appealing to me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know why there is a very thin white stripe at the very, very top unless you e.g. , `CellFrame -> False`?

Answer (score 3):

This gets you part of the way...

```
data = {1, 2, 3, -4, -5, -6, 3};
ndata = PercentForm[#*1.0, 2] & /@ (data / Total@Abs[data]);
labels = {"Asia", "South Asia", "South East Asia", "East Asia","Oceania", "Central Asia", "North Asia"};    

Column[{
  TextCell["GDP Per Capital", "Section", FontColor -> White],
  TextCell["This is a scenario parameter set", FontSize -> 12, 
   FontColor -> White], "", 
  TextCell["WorldGDP in 2020", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 20],
  TextCell["parameter domain:{1,2,3}", FontWeight -> Bold, 
   FontSize -> 12], "", 
  TextCell["% Difference from baseline and contributions in % pts", 
   "TI"],
  Row[{
    BarChart[
     data,
     PlotTheme -> "Business",
     BarOrigin -> Left,
     BarSpacing -> Medium,
     ChartLabels -> labels,
     ChartLegends -> None,
     ChartStyle -> Red,
     ImageSize -> 500],
    Column[ndata, Spacings -> 1.9, Alignment -> Right]
    }]
  },
 Alignment -> Center,
 Background -> {Automatic, {1 -> Darker[Red], 2 -> Darker[Red]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why that little white stripe at the top shows up unless you e.g. , `CellFrame -> False`?

Comment: @Alan -- I don't see it in my output.

Comment: Look closely at your posted image, right above the main title, almost to the border.